# Robocopy not working on Win10 machine

Tags: windows-10, robocopy

I can't get `robocopy` to work within a simple batch file (my first), as I keep getting `ERROR 123 (0x0000007B)` [below]; I've searched via google for a remedy, but found no solution, and tried to copy my simple batch file to another file as shown (`first_batch.bat` exists and `dir first_batch.bat` works just fine).

Any help?

```
$ robocopy first_batch.bat simple_copy.bat

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Started : Tuesday, June 15, 2021 7:48:54
    Source : C:\Users\eric\Desktop\first_batch.bat\
      Dest : C:\Users\eric\Desktop\simple_copy.bat\

      Files : *.*

    Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  2021/06/15 07:48:54 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\Users\eric\Desktop\first_batch.bat\
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: Did you google the error [`ERROR 123 0x0000007B`], otherwise the error is self-explanatory: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` _(likely the result of the trailing backslash in each path)_

Comment: Why are your `.bat` files actually folders?

Comment: As you can see from the head of the cut/paste, I typed the command exactly as shown.  The full path is provided by robocopy itself.  My original bat file, first_batch.bat, exists as verified by "dir" command.  The file "simple_copy.bat" does not exist.  If I edit the command to try and copy a file that doesn't exist, the error message states that accordingly so it isn't a file missing issue.

Comment: Here is the exact command: 
 C:\Users\eric\Desktop>robocopy first_batch.bat simple_copy.bat

Comment: My .bat file is not a folder...not sure why robocopy is showing w/the trailing backslash.  Maybe that is the clue to the issue?

Comment: The thing is that you're passing your batch files as if they were directories. For what you're trying to do, use the ```copy``` command. See my answer for a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for Robocopy is:

```
robocopy <source> <destination> [<file>[ ...]] [<options>]
```

- Both `<source>` and `<destination>` must be directories
- Robocopy cannot copy to the same directory whilst changing the name
- To copy all files in a directory, leave the `<file>` argument empty, or pass `*.*`, remembering you have to pass the `/e` flag to copy all files in all subdirectories

If wanting to copy `%UserProfile%\Desktop\first_batch.bat` to `C:\some_other_dir`:

```
robocopy %UserProfile%\Desktop C:\some_other_dir first_batch.bat
```

To achieve what you're trying to do:

```
copy %UserProfile%\Desktop\first_batch.bat %UserProfile%\Desktop\simple_copy.bat
```

Comment: Ugh, yes, I'm trying to do something goofy.  My original setup was to automate some backing up of a folder and not a specific file.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Then, instead of running into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), try to tell us what are you trying to do, and we'll help.